# Symfony 4 - Set attr to Entity Type

Tags: symfony, checkbox, label, bootstrapping

in my Symfony 4 project I would like to use this bootstrap theme for my checkbox :

[image]

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" checked="">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

I managed to set it up on one of my fields when it's a CheckboxType :: class, like this:

```
->add('inscription', CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Activer l\'inscription',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-label',
                    'for' => 'inscription'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-input',
                    'id' => 'inscription'
                ]
            ])
```

And now I would like use it for Entity Type with multiple choices.

So I've :

```
->add('typesConges', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => TypeConge::class,
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'choice_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-input',
                    'id' => 'typesConges'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-control-label',
                    'for' => 'typesConges'
                ],
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
```

But it doesn't work. I've this :

[image]

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:
Option 1: to create custom form type which is extending the entity type /the backend way/

Option 2: to override the form rendering /the front end way/

I think option 2 is simpler and cleaner and if you use the build in themes, you can override it: [look here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#reusing-parts-of-a-built-in-form-theme)